# xCode - App stop on a not existing breakpoint

Tags: swift, xcode

My app always stop running on this line, even there is no breakpoint and stopping on breakpoint is disabled.

When I click continue it's stop again on the same place to infinite. Basically I'm not able to debug this app anyhow, it started when I've added this func in class.

Any ideas?

[image: Xcode stop on a place where is no breakpoint]

Comment: `MCCVsISDCode` is `nil`, look at the error message and stacktrace in the output section of xcode. And stop force-unwrapping optionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before assign value to MCCVsISDCode kindly init it first.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a user-created breakpoint, but Xcode's way of handling null-referenced crashes. In your case, force-unwrapped value of `MCCVsISDCode` returns `nil`.